# Как отследить ddos атаку?

Tags: debian, ddos

Арендую сервер на Debian 6 под управлением ISP Manager Lite.

Три дня подряд серверу было очень тяжело. Подозрение на ddos атаку. На сервере 30 сайтов под разными пользователями.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать, чтобы отследить на какой сайт была такая нагрузка?

PS: провайдер и хостер молчат, говорят, что они не причем.

Answer (score 2):

путь к логам апача

> /var/log/apache2/access.log
>   /var/log/apache2/error.log

для сайта site.name в файле

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/site.name 
>   строка ErrorLog содержит путь к файлу ошибок по сайту site.name

еще момент: возможно серверу не хватает ресурсов  для обработки всех обращений. по моему опыту имеет смысл пообщаться с разработчиками сайта

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в логах сервера: какое количество запросов куда именно идет. Странный у вас хостер, они первыми должны были вам указать на логи.

Comment: это не хостер. это датацентр, они предоставляют платную консультацию. подскажите, где смотреть логи? есть ли у апача общие логи? я знаю только где логи по каждому сайту смотреть.

Comment: должен быть общий лог, не только отдельные логи для каждого виртуального хоста. обычно в каталоге ../var/log/..    файлы error_log, access_log, а что показывает в логах, которые удалось найти?

Comment: спасибо. сейчас посмотри общие и индивидуальные логи